# Visual Studio Code with Native Script does not recognize all Native Script components

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

Visual Studio Code with Native Script does not recognise Native Script components **sometimes** in the component XML. I have one from the official tutorial and in it the ActionBar is recognized - but GridLayout is not:

'GridLayout' is not a known element:
    1. If 'GridLayout' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

XML looks like this:

```
<ActionBar title="Groceries">
  <!-- On iOS devices, <ActionItem>s are placed from left to right in sequence; you can override that (as the code above does) by providing an ios.position attribute. -->
  <ActionItem text="Share" (tap)="share()" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_share_holo_dark" ios.systemIcon="9" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<GridLayout rows="auto, *">
  <!-- add-bar necessary since we moved the page up 20 over the status bar on iOS-->
  <GridLayout row="0" columns="*, auto" class="add-bar">
    <TextField #groceryTextField [(ngModel)]="grocery" hint="Enter a grocery item" (returnPress)="add()" col="0"></TextField>
    <Image src="res://add" (tap)="add()" col="1"></Image>
  </GridLayout>...
```

It seems totally arbitrary since for example StackLayout is no problem in another XML in same project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in the error log make sure that you have included `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` in the respective `NgModule` (if using lazily loaded modules include the schema there as well)

```
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";

@NgModule({
    schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],

//... more code follows here
```

Side note: it might be just an incomplete snippet but still... the parent `GridLayout` does not have an enclosing tag

Comment: But why is this necessary for some components and not for all?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was happening just for one component html though `NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA` was included in respective module of that file, deleting and creating that file solved the issue for me strange but it did happen.